# Verify claim of service provider: hosting in AWS Frankfurt

Tags: geolocation, ip, saas

I am using a SaaS solution where the provider claims the solutions in hosted in AWS Frankfurt. Can I actually verify that? By GeoIP? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the service IP address which is hosted in AWS? If yes, you can use the demo in ip2location.io to verify the location.